# How to repair screws popping through drywall all along corners?

Tags: drywall, patching-drywall, hole-repair

We had an addition built on our house recently. While adding on, the screws popped through the drywall in the original portion of our house. The screws have cause a small raised bulge every 6” along every corner of the room.

How do I repair the screws that have popped beneath corner tape. Can I take a razer blade to each of the bulges to smooth them out and then mud over it?

Comment: need a lot of pictures to answer

Comment: I've done what you suggest and it worked, at  least for several years.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you'll want to scrape off the raised section. You want to probably add new screws 1" above and below any bulges as well since the movement that caused the screw pops has likely torn the paper which gives drywall all its strength. Then refinish with drywall compound before priming and painting